# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firing twice

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a problem using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapater`, at first it was working fine but now this `adapter` is firing twice. The database reference is only referring one child, but it is always firing twice. The Toast with text "counter" will appear twice

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RequestVisit, RequestViewHolder> requestAdapter = 
    new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RequestVisit, RequestViewHolder>(
    RequestVisit.class,
    R.layout.seekerrequests_layout,
    RequestViewHolder.class,
    requestDatabase.child("2DBwmhGplGMoAlLy6337HZEShi93")
) {
@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(final RequestViewHolder viewHolder, RequestVisit model, int position) {
     Toast.makeText(getContext(), "counter" + 
     viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
requestVisitList.setAdapter(requestAdapter);
```

Comment: Maybe you are using `addValueEventListener`, try using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` this will only get your data from Firebase once and will not listen for updates.

Comment: @AhmedAbidi The `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` handles all the listeners in this case. It intentionally doesn't use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, since it keeps the recycler view in sync with changes in the database.

Comment: @CjZayin: If `populateViewHolder` gets called with two different positions, that means there are two children under  `requestDatabase.child("2DBwmhGplGMoAlLy6337HZEShi93")`. If that doesn't explain it, can you edit your question to include the data under `2DBwmhGplGMoAlLy6337HZEShi93`? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes, there are two children under this `requestDatabase.child("2DBwmhGplGMoAlLy6337HZEShi93")`. Thank you for pointing this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Firebase*Adapter shows a list of items, the child nodes under the location that you attach it to.

If `populateViewHolder` gets called with two different positions, that means there are two children under `requestDatabase.child("2DBwmhGplGMoAlLy6337HZEShi93")`.

Keep in mind that if `2DBwmhGplGMoAlLy6337HZEShi93` is a child node with two properties, then your approach will call `populateViewHolder` for each of those properties.

If you want to show only a single item in the `RecyclerView`, you can create a simple query with:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RequestVisit, RequestViewHolder> requestAdapter = 
    new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RequestVisit, RequestViewHolder>(
    RequestVisit.class,
    R.layout.seekerrequests_layout,
    RequestViewHolder.class,
    requestDatabase.orderByKey().equalTo("2DBwmhGplGMoAlLy6337HZEShi93")
)
```